# Probabilistic Atlas in Advanced Normalization Tools (ANTs)

Tags: pipeline, mask, ants

I'm new in the world of neuroimaging, where I want to quantify certain structures in the brain (Locus coeruleus), using ANTS and a Probabilistic Atlas of the Human Locus Coeruleu (https://www.nitrc.org/projects/lc_7t_prob/)

The creators of the atlas provide a pipeline, which I attach below. My question is, if I have the database of subjects with their respective MRI images (T1, FLAIR, etc), how do I run the pipeline using ANTS, to quantify through the atlas?

I´m currently working on macOS M1

**pipeline**:

````
 #!/bin/bash

module load ANTS/2.2.0

#1. Build averaged MT-on image while registering individual images in an unified step
antsMultivariateTemplateConstruction2.sh -d 3 -o t_ -i 4 -g 0.1 -j 1 -c 5 -k 1 -w 1 -f 8x4x2x1 -s 3x2x1x0 -q 100x70x50x20 -n 1 -r 1 -l 1 -m MI -t Rigid *LC_SN_112*.nii.gz

#2. Co-register MT-off image to the corresponding individual averaged MT-on image
N4BiasFieldCorrection -d 3 -i noMT.nii.gz -o n4_noMT.nii -r 1 -c [50x50x30x20,1e-6] -b [200]; 
gzip n4_noMT.nii

antsRegistration -v 1 -d 3 -o noMT_to_average -n Linear -u 0 -w [0.005,0.995] -r [t_template0.nii.gz,n4_noMT.nii.gz,1] -t Rigid[0.1] -m MI[t_template0.nii.gz,n4_noMT.nii.gz,1,32,Regular,0.25] -c [1000x500x250x100,1e-6,10] -f 12x8x4x2 -s 4x3x2x1vox -x [NULL,NULL] -u 0

antsApplyTransforms -d 3 -i n4_noMT.nii.gz -o noMT_to_template0.nii.gz -r t_template0.nii.gz -n Linear -t noMT_to_average0GenericAffine.mat

#3. Co-register MT-off image to the corresponding individual T1 MP2RAGE image
antsRegistration -v 1 -d 3 -o [noMT_to_T1,noMT_to_T1Warped.nii.gz,noMT_to_T1InverseWarped.nii.gz] -n Linear -u 0 -w [0.005,0.995] -t Rigid[0.1] -m MI[n4mag0000_PSIR_std.nii,n4_noMT.nii.gz,1,32,Regular,0.25] -c [1000x500x250x100,1e-6,10] -f 12x8x4x2 -s 4x3x2x1vox -x [NULL,NULL] -u 0

antsApplyTransforms -d 3 -i n4_noMT.nii.gz -o noMT_to_T1.nii.gz -r n4mag0000_PSIR_std.nii -n Linear -t noMT_to_T10GenericAffine.mat 

#4. Build the study-wise T1 template
antsMultivariateTemplateConstruction2.sh -d 3 -c 5 -g 0.1 -i 6 -q 100x100x70x50x20 -f 10x6x4x2x1 -s 5x3x2x1x0vox -n 0 -o T1TMP_ -r 0 -l 1 -m CC -t SyN -k 1 -v 8gb T1_list_brain_CSFin_denoised_n53.txt 

#5. Coregister T1 template to the ICBM2009b template
source=T1TMP_template0.nii
target=mni_icbm152_t1_tal_nlin_asym_09b_hires_FSL_bbox_struc_brain_CSFin.nii

antsRegistration \
--verbose 1 \
--dimensionality 3 \
--float 0 \
--output \
[T1TMP_53_To_MNI152,T1TMP_53_To_MNI152_Warped.nii.gz,T1TMP_53_To_MNI152_InverseWarped.nii.gz] \
--interpolation Linear \
--use-histogram-matching 0 \
--winsorize-image-intensities [0.005,0.995] \
--initial-moving-transform [${target},${source},1] \
--transform Rigid[0.1] \
--metric CC[${target},${source},1,4] \
--convergence [100x70x50x50,1e-6,10] \
--shrink-factors 8x4x2x1 \
--smoothing-sigmas 3x2x1x0vox \
--transform Affine[0.1] \
--metric MI[${target},${source},1,32,Regular,0.25] \
--convergence [1000x500x250x100,1e-6,10] \
--shrink-factors 12x8x4x2 \
--smoothing-sigmas 4x3x2x1vox \
--transform SyN[0.1,3,0] \/Users/VictorVidal/R08_t1_mprage_sag_p2_iso_20180520172539_5.nii
--metric CC[${target},${source},1,4] \
--convergence [100x100x70x50x20,1e-6,10] \
--shrink-factors 10x6x4x2x1 \
--smoothing-sigmas 5x3x2x1x0vox \

#6. Coregister averaged MT-on images to MNI space
antsApplyTransforms -d 3 -i ${MT_Path}/t_template0.nii.gz -o ${output_Path}/avgMT_to_MNI_TL_CC.nii.gz -r ${MNI_Path}/mni_icbm152_t1_tal_nlin_asym_09b_hires_FSL_bbox_struc_brain_CSFin.nii -n Linear -t ${MNI_Path}/T1TMP_54_CC_To_MNI152_T109b_FSL_bbox_brain_CSFin_RegAllCC1Warp.nii.gz -t ${MNI_Path}/T1TMP_54_CC_To_MNI152_T109b_FSL_bbox_brain_CSFin_RegAllCC0GenericAffine.mat -t ${T1_Path}/T1TMP_${subj}_*1Warp.nii.gz -t ${T1_Path}/T1TMP_${subj}_*.mat -t [${MT_Path}/T1_to_noMT0GenericAffine.mat,1] -t [${MT_Path}/noMT_to_average0GenericAffine.mat,1] -v 1```
````

Comment: Is your data also 7T?

Comment: no, 1.5 and 3 T

Comment: Okay, if the atlas is intended for use at lower field strengths, go for it. It currently seems that you need to run the pipeline in a folder containing all the T1w images. Please edit your question to clarify how you are running this pipeline (from what location relative to your data and script) and what part of this pipeline is failing or not performing as you intend it to.